# Performance of NewRelic Real User Monitoring

Tags: performance, newrelic

We're been using NewRelic Real User Monitoring to track performance and activity.

We've noticed that the browser metrics are showing the majority of time is just Network times.

Even extremely small and simple server pages are showing average times of 3-5 seconds, even though they are just a few k in size and their Web application times and rendering times are mere milliseconds.

The site is hosted in the UK and when I run Chrome's Network Developer Tools I can see the page loading in around 50ms and then the hit to beacon-1.newrelic.com (in the USA) taking a further 500ms.

The majority of our clients do not have the luxury of high bandwidth or modern browsers and I believe that NewRelic itself is causing them a particularly poor user experience.

Are there any ways of making the new relic calls perform better? Can I make new relic call to a local (UK or Europe) based beacon?

I don't want to turn off new relic, but at the moment, it is causing more performance issues than it is alerting us to.

Answer (score 3):

New Relic real user monitoring (RUM) does not affect the page load time for your users. The 500 ms that you are seeing refers to the amount of time it takes for the RUM data we collected from your app to reach our servers here in the U.S. The data is transferred after the pages are loaded, so it doesn't affect the page load at all for your users. This 500 ms of data travel time, therefore, is not part of any of our measurements of the networking, page rendering or DOM processing time.

New Relic calculates network time by first finding the total amount of time your application takes from request to page load, and then subtracting any application server time from that total. It is assumed that the resulting amount of time is "network" time. As such, it doesn't include the amount of time it takes to send that data to New Relic's servers. See this page for more info on how RUM works:

https://newrelic.com/docs/features/how-does-real-user-monitoring-work

If you're worried that there might be a bug or that your numbers don't look accurate, you can always file a support ticket with New Relic so we can look at your account in more detail.